# GCC, compare the effect of using -O2 and using all the optimization flags it turns on

Tags: gcc, optimization

From [gcc5.4 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options), it says

> -O2 turns on all optimization flags specified by -O. It also turns on the following optimization flags:
>
> -fthread-jumps 
>             -falign-functions  -falign-jumps 
>             -falign-loops  -falign-labels 
>             -fcaller-saves 
>             -fcrossjumping 
>             -fcse-follow-jumps, etc

It seems that using -O2 has the same effect of using all the 83 optimization flags turned on by -O2 in gcc 5.4.0 on the performance of the test programs.

However, I compare the running time of the executable files test1 and test2 obtained by

> gcc-5.4 -O2 test.c -o test1

and

> gcc-5.4 -fauto-inc-dec 
>   -fbranch-count-reg 
>   -fcombine-stack-adjustments 
>   -fcompare-elim ... -fthread-jumps -falign-functions ...(all the 83 flags) test.c -o test2

I tested on 20 random generated c programs and running each test case 100000 times to make sure the measurement of running time is accurate enough. *But the result is that using -O2 is averagely about 60% faster than using all the 83 flags.*

I am really confused why the effect of using -O2 is not equivalent to using all the optimization flags it turns on.

I must misunderstood something, but I couldn't find any explanation yet. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_-O1_.28-O2.2C-O3_or_-Os.29_equivalent_to_individual_-foptimization_options.3F

Answer (score 1):

It is a common gotcha. In order to enable (or disable) specific optimizations, you must first enable the optimizer in general, i.e. use one of `-O...` flags, except `-O0` (or just `-O`, which is equivalent to `-O1`).

Comment: plus "Second, the -Ox flags enable many optimizations that are not controlled by any individual -f* option." from the link provided by Marc Glisse https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_-O1_.28-O2.2C-O3_or_-Os.29_equivalent_to_individual_-foptimization_options.3F

Answer (score 0):

The optimisation level affects decisions in other parts of the compiler besides determining which passes get run. These can be during mandatory processes like transforming between internal representations of the code, register allocation etc, so the optimisation level is not exactly equivalent to a set of switches enabling every compiler pass.
Look at [this thread](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-06/msg00483.html) for some discussion on this topic.