# C++: what exactly do -O flag except the flags addition

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, centos5

I have generated C++ code which contains ~200K lines of code, and I'm trying to compile it under CentOS 5.11 with gcc 4.8.5. When I specified the -O1 flag, compilation took 1 min 33 seconds. I found all optimization flags from [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) and [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) pages that -O1 enables and here they are:

- -fcombine-stack-adjustments
- -fcompare-elim
- -fcprop-registers
- -fdefer-pop
- -fforward-propagate
- -fguess-branch-probability
- -fif-conversion
- -fif-conversion2
- -finline-functions-called-once
- -fipa-profile
- -fipa-pure-const
- -fipa-reference
- -fmerge-constants
- -fshrink-wrap
- -fsplit-wide-types
- -ftree-bit-ccp
- -ftree-ccp
- -ftree-ch
- -ftree-copy-prop
- -ftree-copyrename
- -ftree-dce
- -ftree-dominator-opts
- -ftree-dse
- -ftree-fre
- -ftree-sink
- -ftree-slsr
- -ftree-sra
- -ftree-ter

But when I replaced -O1 with these flags compilation time decreased to 34 seconds. Same with -O2 and -O3.

So, here's the question: what exactly do -O flag? If there is nothing more than another flags adding, then the compilation time should not change, but in my case there is a huge difference.

Comment: What is the "flag adding". This option sets the particular level of optimisation adding some work and passes for the compiler

Comment: See gcc's FAQ please.

Comment: Can I somehow simulate -O flag to understand why such a time difference?

Comment: Again, the answer is in the FAQ. https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Is_-O1_.28-O2.2C-O3.2C_-Os_or_-Og.29_equivalent_to_individual_-foptimization_options.3F

Comment: @MarcGlisse You should quote that in an answer.

Comment: Thank you, Marc!

Comment: @NathanOliver No, this should be closed as a dup (this gets asked regularly on this site, there are many candidates).

Comment: @MarcGlisse If you have a target I'll be more than happy to close it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46433381/1918193 is the first that comes, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6454415/1918193 would also work. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/13157352/1918193 .